# How to embed the link into value in a table using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-sheets

My script is shown below. There is a table with 2 columns (Name and URL).

How to use second column value (URL) to embed in the name (like hyperlink)?

Also, is it possible to show all names in a single row? (e.g. name 1    name 2     name 3 ...)

So that, i can click the name and redirect to web site.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var spData = null;
  function doData(json) {
      spData = json.feed.entry;
  }
  
  function drawCell(tr, val) {
      var td = $("<td/>");
      tr.append(td);
      td.append(val);
      return td;
  }
  function drawRow(table, rowData) {
   if (rowData == null) return null;
   if (rowData.length == 0) return null;
   var tr = $("<tr/>");
   table.append(tr);
   for(var c=0; c<2; c++) {
    drawCell(tr, rowData[c]);
   }
   return tr;
  }
  
  function drawTable(parent) {
   var table = $("<table/>");
   parent.append(table);
   return table;
  }
  
  function readData(parent) {
      var data = spData;
      var table = drawTable(parent);
      var rowData = [];
      
      for(var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
          var cell = data[r]["gs$cell"];
          var val = cell["$t"];
          if (cell.col <= 1) {
              drawRow(table, rowData);
              rowData = [];
          }
          rowData.push(val);
      }
      drawRow(table, rowData);
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      readData($("#data"));
  });

  </script>   
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1uwdoylX-De2A8XiIefAJqUBukpy8T2FAEraNN-PzCRE/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Parse Google Spreadsheet with JavaScript</h1> 
<p><div id="data"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Running your code produces two syntax errors : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' and Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: ok. let me change it first.

Comment: Put your all the java script code inside body and it will work. check my answer

Comment: I have modified the script, so that you can run it

Comment: Juhil, is it possible to embed the URL into Name column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging your code, I found out that rowData can be empty and is an array.

Inside that array, you have several different values. The array itself can be empty, contain only non url values or contain urls.

I would first make sure you are getting the data you want from rowData correctly.

Then, in your drawCell method, find out if the value is a link by figuring out if it starts with http/s.

To create an anchor element, do the following:

```
let anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
anchorElement.setAttribute("href", YOUR_LINK);
td.append(anchorElement);
```

***EDIT***

Per OP's latest comment, I am adding the requested code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var spData = null;
  function doData(json) {
      spData = json.feed.entry;
  }
  
  function drawCell(tr, val) {
      var td = $("<td/>");
      tr.append(td);                  //CODE ADDED HERE
      if (val.indexOf("http") !== -1) {
          let anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
          anchorElement.setAttribute("href", val);
          anchorElement.innerHTML = "Link";
          td.append(anchorElement);
      } else {
         td.append(val);
      }
      
      return td;
  }
  function drawRow(table, rowData) {
   if (rowData == null) return null;
   if (rowData.length == 0) return null;
   var tr = $("<tr/>");
   table.append(tr);
   for(var c=0; c<2; c++) {
    drawCell(tr, rowData[c]);
   }
   return tr;
  }
  
  function drawTable(parent) {
   var table = $("<table/>");
   parent.append(table);
   return table;
  }
  
  function readData(parent) {
      var data = spData;
      var table = drawTable(parent);
      var rowData = [];
      
      for(var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
          var cell = data[r]["gs$cell"];
          var val = cell["$t"];
          if (cell.col <= 1) {
              drawRow(table, rowData);
              rowData = [];
          }
          rowData.push(val);
      }
      drawRow(table, rowData);
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      readData($("#data"));
  });

  </script>   
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1uwdoylX-De2A8XiIefAJqUBukpy8T2FAEraNN-PzCRE/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Parse Google Spreadsheet with JavaScript</h1> 
<p><div id="data"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the row data is correct. I just want to retrieve 2 columns in Google sheet table. one for Name and one for URL.

Comment: @Carlson - you asked ```How to use second column value (URL) to embed in the name (like hyperlink)?```. The answer posted above shows how to create an anchor element (hyperlink).

Comment: Could you help to post the whole code? I am new on javascript. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Carlson - I have updated my answer. If it helped you, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below,

```html
<body>
<h1>Parse Google Spreadsheet with JavaScript</h1> 
<div id="data"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var spData = null;
  function doData(json) {
      spData = json.feed.entry;
  }

  function drawCell(tr, val) {
      var td = $("<td/>");
      tr.append(td);
      td.append(val);
      return td;
  }
  function drawRow(table, rowData) {
      if (rowData == null) return null;
      if (rowData.length == 0) return null;
      var tr = $("<tr/>");
      table.append(tr);
      for(var c=0; c<2; c++) {
          drawCell(tr, rowData[c]);
      }
      return tr;
  }

  function drawTable(parent) {
      var table = $("<table/>");
      parent.append(table);
      return table;
  }

  function readData(parent) {
      var data = spData;
      var table = drawTable(parent);
      var rowData = [];

      for(var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
          var cell = data[r]["gs$cell"];
          var val = cell["$t"];
          if (cell.col <= 1) {
              drawRow(table, rowData);
              rowData = [];
          }
          rowData.push(val);
      }
      drawRow(table, rowData);
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      readData($("#data"));
  });

  </script>   
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1uwdoylX-De2A8XiIefAJqUBukpy8T2FAEraNN-PzCRE/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello Juhil, it doesn't work. the result is same as before.